How to prevent blank lines and remove extra spaces in C word-per-line output?
I'm reading K&R's The C Programming Language and currently working on Exercise 1-12. The issue I'm facing isn't with completing the exercise itself, but with fixing a bug that has come up as a result of my code.
The code produces an unwanted blank line when encountering two or more spaces. I want to ensure that the output has no blank lines and that extra spaces are trimmed.
My solution.
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int c;
    
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        if (c == ' ' || c == '\t')
        {
            printf("\n");
        }
        else
        {
            putchar(c);
        }
    }
}

Problematic output
bash >>> ./Exercises/ex12
hello  everyone
hello
 
everyone

I tried solving it based on Ex 1-9 [2], but no luck.
#include <stdio.h>
#define PREVCHAR 'a'

int main(void)
{
    int c, prevc = PREVCHAR;
    
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        if (c == ' ' && prevc == ' ')
        {
            printf("");
        } else if (c == ' ' && prevc != ' ')
        {
            printf("\n");
        } else
        {
            putchar(c);
            prevc = c;
        }
    }
}

[1] = Write a program that prints its input one word per line.
[2] = Write a program to copy its input to its output, replacing each string of one or more blanks by a single blank.

Please post the text of the exercise.

You also need to set prevc inside the second if.

Also, in your next version, pay attention to newlines (\n) and tabs (\t).

I think you want to achieve the following output:
hello 
everyone

The reason there is a blank line is that your algorithm just replaces each space/tab by a new line.
Your principal idea to simply check if the previous char was a space or a tab is correct.
The problem is, you only set prev in case it is not a blank space.
Because of that, prev will never be a space or a tab.
Furthermore, I suggest doing something like this:
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int c;
    bool previousWasBlank = false;
    
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        if (c == ' ' || c == '\t')
        {
            if (!previousWasBlank)
                printf("\n");

            previousWasBlank = true;
        }
        else
        {
            putchar(c);
            previousWasBlank = false;
        }
    }
}


Thanks, @neldav, for your response! It genuinely helped me resolve the bugs in my first code. Although another bug presented itself, I was able to resolve it myself and learned the value of using states (booleans or symbolic constants).
